# Re-enable GitHub two-factor authentication with Authenticator app when switching to a new smartphone

Tags: ios, github, two-factor-authentication, authenticator

I changed my iPhone recently. Now, when I log in to GitHub, it asks me to enter the code from my Authenticator app.

But the old GitHub entry is gone in the Authenticator app on the new phone! Apparently, it was not transferred with the rest of the data from the old to the new iPhone.

How can I re-enable GitHub two-factor authentication with the Authenticator app on my new smartphone?

**Note:**

The Authenticator app is the [Microsoft Authenticator app for iPhone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-authenticator/id983156458)

[image: MS Authenticator]

Comment: You will need to use one of the recovery codes that you saved when you set up 2FA originally.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for the comment! Actually, instead of that I used the **SMS code** that was sent to the Messages app on the iPhone that was one of the alternative methods of 2FA that I had previously set up. That worked OK for me to login to GitHub. I did not have to use the recovery codes that I saved when I set up 2FA originally. Do you think your comment (and my comment here) should be added to the answer to make it more complete?

Comment: **To those who vote to close as not abour programming:** we have plenty of similar, legitimate, highly upvoted questions like this: [Highest scored 'github+two-factor-authentication' questions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github%2btwo-factor-authentication?tab=Votes). For example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25550481/967621), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43746923/967621), and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68824508/967621).

Comment: **To those who vote to close for this reason:** *"This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers"*: **Note that GitHub is a software tool primarily used by programmers.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the upper-right corner of any GitHub page, click your profile photo, then click "Settings" ("gear" icon).

[image: settings]

- In the "Access" section of the sidebar, click "Password and authentication".

[image: password]

- In the "Two-factor authentication" section of the page, under "two-factor authentication":
- Under "Authenticator app", click on "Manage Authenticator app" (<kbd>...</kbd> icon), click on "Disable". The page will refresh.

[image: authenticator]

- Under "Authenticator app", click "Add". This will display the QR code image on the page.
- Open in the smartphone the Authenticator app. Click on the <kbd>+</kbd> icon to add an account.

[image: Authenticator app: + to add an account]

- Click on "Other". Scan with the phone camera the QR code on the GitHub web page above.

[image: QR code]

- After scanning, the Authenticator app displays a six-digit code that you can enter on GitHub.
- The Authenticator app saves your account on GitHub.com and generates a new authentication code every few seconds. On GitHub, type the code into the field under "Verify the code from the app". Click "Save".

**References:**

[Configuring two-factor authentication - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/configuring-two-factor-authentication) - how to set up two-factor authentication from scratch (before Authenticator was used for the first time).